Name on Envelope
I have a spreadsheet with one to two names per row, broken into first and last names. I'm trying to concatenate the names, the result depending on whether the last name is the same or different, or even not present. My goal is to have a cell to use for the envelope name in a form that is professional.



fname1
lname1
fname2
lname2




Joe
Smith
Linda
Smith


Danny
Larson
Shannon
Carter


Bart
Simpson
blank
blank



I am trying to figure out a formula that would result in
"Joe and Linda Smith" (concat fname1, " and ", fname2 and lname1 if lname1 and lname2 are the same)
"Danny Larson and Shannon Carter" (concat fname1, lname1, " and " fname2, lname2 if lname1 and lname2 are NOT the same)
"Bart Simpson" (concat fname1 and lname1 only if fname2 and lname2 are empty)
I've tried all kind of combos with no real breakthroughs, I think it's just outside my skill range.

Thanks for the fun task ;)
If you have Microsoft 365, you could use LET etc. to name the parts - it makes it easy to understand the formulas. Please adjust the logic to match your input.
Enter this in the first cell (F2 in the example), no need to fill-down:
Start a new line of text inside a cell in Excel - Microsoft Support
=BYROW(A2:D10, LAMBDA(row_, LET(
fname1, INDEX(row_, 1, 1), lname1, INDEX(row_, 1, 2),
fname2, INDEX(row_, 1, 3), lname2, INDEX(row_, 1, 4),
IFS(
AND(lname1 = lname2, NOT(ISBLANK(lname1)), ISBLANK(fname1), ISBLANK(fname2)),
CONCAT(lname1, " and ", lname2),
AND(lname1 = lname2, NOT(ISBLANK(lname1))),
CONCAT(fname1, " and ", fname2, " ", lname1),
TRUE, TRIM(
CONCAT(fname1, " ", lname1,
IF(AND(LEN(fname1 & lname1), LEN(fname2 & lname2)), " and ", ""),
fname2, " ", lname2))))))



I would have logic that sees if there's a pair, and if so combine accordingly. If not, confirm there is no name in the second, then print the first full name. Then, if all fails, it prints both names individually together.
=IF(B2=D2, A2 &" and "& C2 &" "& D2 , IF(ISBLANK(C2),A2 &" "& B2, A2 &" "& B2 &" and "& C2 &" "& D2 ) )

